# Problemas ao realizar Build com PostSharp no AppVeyor

Tags: c#, postsharp

Estou com problemas para fazer `build` do meu projeto no `AppVeyor`, (localmente funciona) pois a licença fica no `regedit`.
Verifiquei que é necessário criar um arquivo **postsharp.config** e `inserir` informações da licença, mas mesmo assim não deu certo

**Minha licença está válida.**

```
 C:\projects\webapibase\packages\PostSharp.5.0.41\build\PostSharp.targets(314,5):
 error PS0260: License error. The license
 xxx is not allowed to be loaded from
 C:\projects\webapibase\Service\postsharp.config.
 [C:\projects\webapibase\Service\Service.csproj]
 C:\projects\webapibase\packages\PostSharp.5.0.41\build\PostSharp.targets(314,5):
 error PS0242: License error. No valid license key has been installed.
 Please visit https://www.postsharp.net/purchase to acquire a license
 of PostSharp. To register a license key, use PostSharp Essentials or
 start the evaluation period, execute the program
```

O arquivo **postsharp.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.postsharp.org/1.0/configuration">
  <License Value="xxxx" />
</Project>
```

<sub>*PS*.: Tenho o mesmo projeto no TFS e o Build lá funciona normal (não necessita do arquivo), provavelmente o PostSharp detecta que é uma build machine e ignora o check da licença.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, a solução é adicionar antes do Build a Key no Registro:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SharpCrafters\PostSharp 3" /v LicenseKey /t REG_SZ /d <your_license>
```

[image]