# Alternativas OpenSource ao PostSharp

Tags: c#, atributos, postsharp

Alguém conhece uma boa alternativa **OpenSource** ao **PostSharp**?
Sei que ele possui a versão Free, mas estou desenvolvendo alguns pacotes Nuget utilizando atributos e acho a dependência do PostSharp pesada e a qualquer momento eles podem começar a cobrar, depende de licença.. inclusive estou com um problema chato com ele o AppVeyor referente a licença [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261840/problemas-ao-realizar-build-com-postsharp-no-appveyor).

Preciso especificamente trabalhar com atributos Custom assim como fazemos no PostSharp, ontem achei um e comecei a testar: https://github.com/AntyaDev/KingAOP , mas não me atendeu 100% e o projeto está a 5 anos sem alteração.

Sugestões são bem vindas.

Comment: VÊ esse: https://github.com/Virtuoze/NConcern

Comment: @Maniero testarei hoje mais tarde, obrigado pela pronta resposta.